# Existence & uniqueness of radix representation by decrementing descent

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

I'm reading a proof in George E. Andrew's *Number Theory* of the Basis Representation Theorem (i.e. each positive integer $n$ has a unique representation in base $k$), and I'm having some difficulty. For reference, the argument in the proof runs like this:

Suppose we have a representation of $n$ as
$$n = a_0k^s + a_1k^{s-1} + ... + a_{s}.$$

If some of the trailing $a_i$ are $0$, then exclude them so that
$$n = a_0k^s + a_1k^{s-1} + ... + a_{s-t}k^t,$$
where now $a_0 \neq 0$ and $a_{s-t} \neq 0$. Then
$$ 
\begin{align*}
n-1 &=  a_0k^s + a_1k^{s-1} + ... + a_{s-t}k^t - 1\\
&= a_0k^s + a_1k^{s-1} + ... + (a_{s-t}-1)k^t + k^t - 1\\
&= a_0k^s + a_1k^{s-1} + ... + (a_{s-t}-1)k^t + \sum_{j=0}^{t-1}(k-1)k^j.
\end{align*}
$$

Let $b_k(n)$ denote the number of representations of $n$ in the base $k$. We just showed that for every representation of $n$, we can find one for $n-1$, so that 
$$b_k(n) \leq b_k(n-1).$$

With this fact, the proof continues and concludes 
$$1 \leq b_k(k^n) \leq b_k(n) \leq b_k(1) = 1, \ \ \ (1.1)$$

So we have existence and uniqueness. $\blacksquare$

**My question:** Part of the theorem's hypothesis says each $a_i$ is such that $0 \leq a_i \leq k-1$. I want to understand where the proof fails if you remove this requirement. If you allow $a_i$'s to be negative, then I see why the proof fails, because then $1$ can be expressed in numerous ways, so that $b_k(1) \neq 1$ (for example $1 = -(k-1)\cdot k^0 + 1\cdot k^1$). However, I don't see where the proof fails in the case where you require $a_i \geq 0$, but allow them to be arbitrarily large (i.e. $0 \leq a_i < \infty)$. In this case, $1$ still has a unique representation, so the problem lies somewhere in the left side of $(1.1)$ rather than the right side. I can see the issue with a particular example: if you allow arbitrarily large $a_i$, then you could have for instance $3 = 1\cdot3^1 = 3*3^0$, so that $b_3(3) = 2$, while $b_3(1) = 1$, so $b_3(3) > b_3(1) = 1$, which is the opposite of the inequality $b_k(n) \leq b_k(n-1)$ in the proof, but I don't see how the proof fails in this case. I'm rather confused, so insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow digits greater than $k-1$, then uniqueness fails like this:

In base $5$, let's represent the number $6$. We can write it as:

$11_5$

or as

$6_5$

This is why we don't have a digit for $6$, in base $5$, but if we did, we would lose uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks, but my real question is where the proof fails if you eliminate this part of the hypothesis. I see that uniqueness is lost, but I don't see where the proof doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that different representations of $n$ can result in the same representation for $n-1$ if $a_i$ is allowed to be any nonnegative integer.
For example, allowing for such $a_i$ but following the process Andrews describes we find
$$\begin{array}{rcll}
10 = 1\cdot 10^1
    &\rightarrow&
    9 = (1-1) 10^1 + (10-1) 10^0 
    = 9\cdot 10^0 &\\
10 = 10\cdot 10^0 
    &\rightarrow&
    9 = (10-1) 10^0
    = 9\cdot 10^0. &\quad(!)
\end{array}$$
Thus, it does not follow that
$b_k(n)\le b_k(n-1)$.
It is critical to Andrews' argument that different representations of $n$ result in different representations for $n-1$.
This only occurs if $0\le a_i\le k-1$.